# Integer solutions of the equation $7(a^2+b^2)=(c^2+d^2)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

> What are all the integer solutions of the equation $7(a^2+b^2)=(c^2+d^2)$

First thing to note is that $c=7C$ and $d=7D$ and substituting it in the original equation yields an equation that is analogous to this equation.So by Fermat's method of infinite descent,there can be no solution except $(0,0,0,0)$. But I am struggling with the proof writing.

**FORMAL PROOF:**

It is enough to solve the equation for positive $a,b,c,d$. Let $(a,b,c,d)=(A,B,C,D)$ be a quadruple satisfying the equation such that $C$ is the smallest positive integer value that $c$ can take. Note that for $7$ to divide the right side,it must divide each of $C$ and $D$. This can be proven by considering the residues that a perfect square leaves mod $7$. Then $C=7C_0,D=7D_0,C_0<C$, and substitution yields $(A^2+B^2)=7(C_0^2+D_0^2)$ and again substituting $A=7A_0,B=7B_0$ yields $7(A_0^2+B_0^2)=C_0^2+D_0^2$ but then $c=C_0$ is the smallest positive integer that satisfies the equation.This contradicts our initial assumption and hence there exists no positive or negative solution of the equation.Hence the only solution is $(0,0,0,0)$.

Is my formal proof correct?How can it be improved?Any advice regarding the proof writing will be appreciated.

Comment: Your proof is correct and well written in my opinion! Nice work!

Comment: Your proof is correct!

Comment: @sranthrop@Nikhil,thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 4):

Your proof is correct, but you should list the squares mod $7$ and explain why that works, rather than just saying.

Here is another proof - sums of squares can often usefully be considered modulo $8$, where the squares are $0,1,4$ and in particular every odd square $\equiv 1$ because $(2m+1)^2=4m(m+1)+1$.

Assume that $a,b,c,d$ have no common factor (we'd cancel it) and not all are zero. We have $8(a^2+b^2)=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$. This cannot happen if any of $a,b,c,d$ are odd, because the maximum sum of residues mod $8$ on the right is then $7$. Hence they must all be even. Contradiction. Hence all are zero.

Answer (score 3):

In a sum of two squares, the primes of the form $4k+3$ appear with even exponent.

$7$ is of this form.

In $7(a^2+b^2)=(c^2+d^2)$, $7$ appears with odd exponent on the LHS and with even exponent on the RHS. Hence, the numbers must be zero.